Why Is Radioactive Decay Essential in Maintaining the Earth's Magnetic Field?
I remember reading that the heat produced by decaying radioactive elements play an important role in maintaining the Earth's magnetic field. Is it true? If so, I would like to know how big of a contribution it actually has.
If there is a research on this topic, please let me know.
Also, what other factors are involved in forming and maintaining the magnetic field?
Thanks in advance.

There some memory fragments which time probably shortened to a degree that it becomes incomprehensible on the boundary to incorrect:
Earth's magnetic field is kept up and generated by convection within the liquid part of Earth's core, the outer core. Convection usually is driven by heat gradients larger than the adiabatic one; convection then ensures that the temperature gradient is reduced to the adiabatic temperature gradient (as convection is the most efficient form of temperature transport within gases or liquids).
Decay of radioactive elements does add to the overall heat flux of Earth. While it is possible to reasonably well get a hand onto the overall heat flux through Earth's surface, it is difficult to distinguish well the sources. The two main sources for the heat flux from Earth (besides the incoming solar radiation) are the primordial heat (heat generated during formation of Earth), and the radioactive decay.
Now, the heat flux from the Earth's inner core through the outer core where the magnetic field is generated into the lower mantle is very difficult to judge - as we cannot get a good handle on the radiogenic heating at those depths. Depending on how you estimate the contributions to the heat flux from the inner Earth core (primordial, radiogenic), the contribution of radiogenic heating could be large enough that only its presence enables to upkeep the adiabatic temperature gradient within the outer core, and via proxy of that convection in the outer core and thus indirectly the Earth's magnetic field.
